# Why does std::forward not work in the lambda body?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, mutable, perfect-forwarding

```
#include <utility>

void f(auto const& fn1)
{
    {
        auto fn2 = std::forward<decltype(fn1)>(fn1);
        auto fn3 = std::forward<decltype(fn2)>(fn2); // ok
        fn3();
    }

    [fn2 = std::forward<decltype(fn1)>(fn1)]
    {
        auto const fn3 = fn2;
        auto fn4 = std::forward<decltype(fn3)>(fn3); // ok
        fn4();
    
        auto fn5 = std::forward<decltype(fn2)>(fn2); // error
        fn5();
    }();
}

int main()
{
    f([] {});
}
```

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ePPY96cPM)

**Why does** `std::forward` **not work in the lambda body?**

---

***Updated Information:***

*g++ is ok, but clang++ rejects it. Who is correct?*

Comment: Why you not write it as a "normal" template without the auto parameter. In your case all the decltype stuff confuses me as a reader a lot. Having simple `typename T` makes it much easier to understand. And I also have a problem to understanding why you use const& as it is not a forwarding reference but use std::forward.

Comment: It is a minimized POC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang is correct to reject it.

`decltype(fn2)` gives the type of `fn2`, suppose the lambda closure type is `T`, then it'll be `T`. Function-call operator of the lambda is const-qualified, then `std::forward<decltype(fn2)>(fn2)` fails to be called. The template argument for [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is specified as `T` explicitly, then `std::forward<decltype(fn2)>` is supposed to accept `T&` (and `T&&`) as its parameter type, but a `const` `fn2` can't be bound to reference to **non-const**.

As the workaround you might mark the lambda as `mutable`.

```
[fn2 = std::forward<decltype(fn1)>(fn1)] mutable
{
    auto fn3 = std::forward<decltype(fn2)>(fn2); // fine
    fn3();
}();
```

Comment: But `fn2` is lvalue. How did it bind to to `T&&`?

Comment: @TheScore Sorry I forgot mentioning the overload taking lvalue-reference.

Comment: Thank you your edit perfectly answered my doubt.

Answer (score 5):

The captures of a lambda are members of the closure class, and the body is `operator() const`.

You are trying to move a data member of a class in a `const` member function, which is what the compiler error is telling you

```
note: candidate function template not viable: 1st argument ('const (lambda at <source>:20:7)') would lose const qualifier
```

Comment: My intent is copy, rather than move, `fn2` to `fn3`, why is `std::forward<decltype(fn2)>(fn2)` not of `T const&` in the lambda body?

Comment: @xmllmx because it is a value capture, not a reference capture

Comment: I still have questions, see my updated question.

Comment: I think forwarding a const object should produce `T const&` rather than `T&&`.

Comment: @xmllmx it's a mutable object in a const context